# How to pass runtime parameter value to download stream project?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

My downstream project is a parameterized build project. It requires a string parameter. The value of the parameter is generated from its upstream project. How can I pass that runtime value from upstream to downstream?
Both downstream and upstream are freestyle projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to pass values to input variables of downstream projects.

Comment: the problem is how to get the value from build step? For example, if I have defined a variable `var`, how can I pass the value `var=$var` to the downstream job?

Comment: Use [EnvyInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to create environment variables in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Please the Post Build Action in the Jenkins related to the parameterized build. Which can pass the values to the next build actions.

Answer (score -1):

[Yes, Post Build Action has 'Trigger Parameterized build on other projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w1Qo.png)
Thank you very much.